# How to check if current page is a parent item or child item in a given menu

Tags: menus, sub-menu

I'm trying to build a submenu into my theme, and I've got it working except it shows even on top-level pages that don't have children.

How could I check that the current page (or current menu item) is either a parent or a child item (I'm pretty sure that logic holds up) in a given menu?

At the moment I'm trying to do this check outside of the menu function, because it has wrapper divs and a title that I won't want to show at all in cases where the page isn't a parent or a child. However, if the best answer to my problem is to output the whole thing via a custom walker I'm open to how that might work too.

Thanks in advance.

Edit: I've gotten a bit further but am now stuck, I can capture the submenu as a variable, but I can't do the check "If there's nothing in the submenu, show nothing". In the below code, `$submenu` doesn't return false when there are no items even with that `fallback_cb => false`.

```
$main_menu_id = 2; // Change to the main menu id for this install
$top_menu_id = 4; // Change to the top menu id for this install
$in_menu = '';

// Check what menu the page is in, if any
if( coepio_is_in_menu( $main_menu_id ) ) {
    $in_menu = 'main-nav';
} else if( coepio_is_in_menu( $top_menu_id ) ) {
    $in_menu = 'top-nav';
}

// If the page is in a menu...
if( $in_menu != '' ) {

    // Capture submenu as a variable
    $args = array( 
                'theme_location' => $in_menu,
                'echo'           => '0',
                'sub_menu'       => true,
                'falback_cb'     => false
        );
    $submenu = wp_nav_menu( $args );

    // If the menu has items
    if( $submenu ) {
        echo 'Menu is good to go';
        ?>
        <div id="submenu" class="sidebar cf" role="navigation">

            <div class="widget">
                <div id="submenu-title" class="widget-title">
                    <h4>In This Section</h4>
                </div>
                <div class="widget-content">
                    <?php 
                    echo $submenu; 
                    ?>
                </div>
            </div>

        </div><!-- #submenu -->
        <?php
    }

}
```

You may have noticed that `'sub_menu' => true` in the `$args`. Here's the code that handles that, taken from another SO post.

```
// Submenus - required for the submenu (above) to work
// filter_hook function to react on sub_menu flag
function coepio_submenu( $sorted_menu_items, $args ) {
  if ( isset( $args->sub_menu ) ) {
$root_id = 0;

// find the current menu item
foreach ( $sorted_menu_items as $menu_item ) {
  if ( $menu_item->current ) {
    // set the root id based on whether the current menu item has a parent or not
    $root_id = ( $menu_item->menu_item_parent ) ? $menu_item->menu_item_parent : $menu_item->ID;
    break;
  }
}

$menu_item_parents = array();
foreach ( $sorted_menu_items as $key => $item ) {
  // init menu_item_parents
  if ( $item->ID == $root_id ) $menu_item_parents[] = $item->ID;

  if ( in_array( $item->menu_item_parent, $menu_item_parents ) ) {
    // part of sub-tree: keep!
    $menu_item_parents[] = $item->ID;
  } else {
    // not part of sub-tree: away with it!
    unset( $sorted_menu_items[$key] );
  }
}

return $sorted_menu_items;
  } else {
return $sorted_menu_items;
  }
}
add_filter( 'wp_nav_menu_objects', 'coepio_submenu', 10, 2 );
```

Answer (score 1):

I typically use something like:

```
$submenu = wp_list_pages(
    array(
        'child_of' => $post->ID,
        'echo'     => false,
    )
);

if ( $submenu )
    printf(
        '<ul class="submenu">%s</ul>',
        $submenu
    );
```

`$submenu` will evaluate false (empty) if there are no children for the current page.

Comment: I can see this would work if everything is set up properly (E.g. pages actually have the correct parent set etc), however I wonder if there's a way to do it by querying the menu rather than via the pages? The submenu I've made queries the menu, not the page heirarchy, so it would be ideal to do the check on the menu as well. There's always the possibility of the menus not matching up to the page hierarchy.

Comment: Well even if you're using `wp_nav_menu`, you can still use the `echo` arg to capture the output instead. Am I close? Perhaps it might be best if you post some of your current code.

Comment: Good point. I'll give that a try and post code if I'm still stuck. Thanks.

Comment: I've made an edit with some code. If you've got time to check if you can see why `$submenu` is always returning true that would be awesome :)